# How can i find words which are greater than given number of length in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a simple String in python.

```
str ="A quick brown fox jump over the lamp."
length = 3
```

I want to check all the words in sentence which are greater than the length of `3`. we want to check the string length is greater than `3` to the given String. We have to find all the words (substrings separated by a space) which are greater than the given length 3.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Comment: @Prune Sir I hardly find the solution to that simple problem. I am new in Python programming skills. I don't find the exact solution soon I solve this problem hardly and now some other good answers are available. that's why I ask the question.

Comment: You don't *find* the exact solution; that's not how you learn to program.  You learn the individual skills, analyze your problem, and craft a solution.

Comment: Ok, @Prune I will take care of that process and try to follow your instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

shorter:

```
s ="A quick brown fox jump over the lamp."
length = 3
print( [ x for x in s.split() if len(x) > length ] )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with regex by searching for a pattern of \w following by curly braces and the number of chars that you would like to find in a given string.

```
import re

s ="A quick brown fox jump over the lamp."
length = 3
print(re.findall("\w{{{},}}".format(length), s))
```

OR in python 3.6 and above

```
print(re.findall(f"\w{{{length},}}", s))
```

Output

```
['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jump', 'over', 'the', 'lamp']
```